# Using placeholders in Jetty contextXML file

Tags: maven, jetty

I'm using Maven and jetty plugin to local start my application.
And I have seen way that you could use placeholders in Jetty contextXML.
Here is part of my pom.xml (located in separate module) where I connected jetty plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <stopKey>${test.jetty.stop-key}</stopKey>
        <stopPort>${test.jetty.stop-port}</stopPort>
        <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/${test.contextPath}/*</contextPath>
        </webAppConfig>
        <httpConnector>
            <port>${jetty.port}</port>
            <host>${jetty.host}</host>
        </httpConnector>
        <contextXml>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jetty/${jetty.mode}-jetty.xml</contextXml>
    </configuration>
<dependencies>
...
</dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Here is part of my stub-jetty.xml file:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
...
<New id="loggerCF" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jms/logger/connectionFactory/loggerCF</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <Arg>tcp://${active-mq.host}:${active-mq.port}</Arg>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
</Configure>
```

Parameters "active-mq.host" and "active-mq.port" defined in **main** pom.xml file.

When I run I receive next exception:

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 6: tcp://${active-mq.host}:${active-mq.port}
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail (URI.java:2848)
    ...
```

So I understand that Jetty not understand that needed to change placeholders to values from Maven properties. How to fix this problem or what I could read about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly reference properties defined in `Maven` configurations. The desired behavior could be achieved with [System Properties](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/reference-section.html#jetty-xml-system-property). You can set it up as a part of `jetty-maven-plugin` [configuration](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html), the required option is `systemProperties` or `systemPropertiesFile`.

Here is a rough example (please note that I haven't checked it):

```xml
<New class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <Arg>tcp://<SystemProperty name="active-mq.host"/>:<SystemProperty name="active-mq.port"/></Arg>
</New>
```

and `pom`:

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
        <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
                <name>active-mq.host</name>
                <value>${active-mq.host}</value>
            </systemProperty>
            <systemProperty>
                <name>active-mq.port</name>
                <value>${active-mq.port}</value>
            </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I know this way of using systemProperty in plugin configuration area. But somewhere I saw using approach as I described in question but still can't find the correct example in Google :) I will continue the search ...